# Consuming Wikipedia API by Universal App Windows 10 C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, wikipedia-api

I'm newbie in C# and I have no idea how to consume a JSON from an API. I would like to get this JSON: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=java&origin=*

And transform it in an C# Object. How Can I make that? Anyone has a very simple example? Also, I would like to understand the code.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I want to make a Universal App. 
Sorry for the very simple question.

Thanks! =D

Comment: you can find the concept of how to achieve that if you just google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `json.NET` to get an json object. And the use 
`string serializedjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);` to create an serialized string.